# Can a Mii be transferred to the Switch from another Nintendo console?

Tags: nintendo-switch

Miis are not as prominent on the Switch as in other Nintendo consoles, but they can still be created and also transferred to Amiibos.

Is it possible to transfer a Mii from a Wii, Wii U or 3DS to the Switch?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but only if you have an Amiibo to transfer it (which it sounds like you already figured out).

Nintendo [answered some questions Kotaku had](https://kotaku.com/nintendo-answers-and-avoids-our-switch-questions-1791402953).  This was in one of the responses.

> You can send/receive Mii characters through local wireless communication between Nintendo Switch systems, or use an amiibo figure to transfer Mii Characters from Wii U and Nintendo 3DS systems.

Having said that, it sounds like this is a uni-directional transfer as Switch Miis have some new properties that previous Miis did not have.

Comment: I see, I hadn't realised that registering an Amiibo also copies the Mii into it. I was looking for a special function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am very disappointed to discover I cannot transfer Miis from my Nintendo Account, Miitomo or the Wii. You cannot use QR codes. Only via Amiibo from the Wii U and 3DS systems.

Your other options are to start from scratch or to use a look-alike.

(At least, that is the situation on launch day. They may change this one day.)